How to turn off git decoration in explorer for folder, not for the changed files?
Although Git decoration in the explorer is useful, it is very confusing, I don't want to apply decoration on folders containing emphasized items, just applying it to files is enough.
Is there a way to customize this decoration?

There is only an option to enable/disable git decoration.

I think you will have to open a feature request for this on the vscode GitHub repo.

There are 3 possible workarounds you can use,
Workaround 1: Use extension
Use GitLens or Git Graph
Workaround 2: Modify workspace settings
In the JSON settings file, disable Git decorations completely
"git.decorations.enabled": false

and then hide untracked files
"explorer.excludeGitIgnore": true

Workaround 3: Manually adjust decorations
In the JSON settings file, update workbench.colorCustomizations section for gitDecoration
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"gitDecoration.untrackedResourceForeground": "#d3d3d3",
"gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#d3d3d3",
"gitDecoration.deletedResourceForeground": "#d3d3d3",
"gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground": "#d3d3d3",
"gitDecoration.conflictingResourceForeground": "#d3d3d3" }

